# AngularJS search - how to cancel previous search

Tags: angularjs, race-condition

I use this code to search items from backend:

```
$scope.$watch('vm.searchTerm', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(oldValue != newValue) {                              
    vm.loadingProducts = true;                  
    myService.findItemsByTerm(searchTerm).then(function(response) {
        vm.myItems = response.data;
        vm.loadingProducts = false;                     
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('error search');
      });   
    } 
});
```

There are a lot of items in backend so the search could take longer.
And sometimes it can be that an older request is slower than a newer request - the older request than overwrites **vm.myItems**.
Is there a best practice how to solve this problem - can I cancel an older request somehow with AngularJS?

Comment: there isn't a way to cancel a request that's already been sent to the server. What you should do is not start another search if a request is already in progress.  You can check `if (vm.loadingProducts)` then don't call `myService.findItemsByTerm`

Comment: you can timeout a promise with a little work

Comment: You could use an interceptor to add a stamp on your request and if the response stamp is older than your "global" stamp just omit the value.